# What code is NOT allowed inside ECMAScript 2015 classes?

Tags: javascript, class, syntax

> JavaScript [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes), introduced in ECMAScript 2015, are primarily syntactical sugar over JavaScript's existing prototype-based inheritance

What kind of code is **NOT** allowed to be used within ECMAScript 2015 class `{}` brackets? Can private variables, constants and functions be declared inside the `class` brackets?

e.g.

```
class Person{
  constructor(n){ this.name = n;}  
  const HELLO = 'Hello!';  //is this allowed?
  saySomething (m){ console.log(this.name + ' says ' + (m || HELLO)) }
}
```

Comment: The very MDN article you linked explains which syntax can be used for defining methods.

Comment: You'd likely be better off asking the opposite (what's not allowed), if that's what you're interested in.

Comment: @ryanwebjackson, I just reviewed the question following your suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this article](https://javascript.info/class), the basic class syntax looks like this:

```
class MyClass {
  constructor(...) {
    // ...
  }
  method1(...) {}
  method2(...) {}
  get something(...) {}
  set something(...) {}
  static staticMethod(..) {}
  // ...
}
```

The provided sample code would throw a `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` error on Chrome; private `const` or `var` are **not allowed** inside the `class`declaration. One alternative could be using [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) (Immediately Invoked Function Expression):

```
Person = (function(){

    const HELLO = 'Hello!';

    class Person{
      constructor(n){ this.name = n;}    
      saySomething (m){ console.log(this.name + ' says ' + (m || HELLO)) 
    }

    return Person;
})();
```

For more details, see the [ECMAScript 2015 classes](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-class-definitions) spec.

Comment: In ES2015+ classes, fields need to be initialized in the constructor using `this.field=value`. Strangely, though, in Typescript classes, field initialization is allowed, and IMO makes the class easier to read, and easier to hint for an IDE.